# not getting desired 1-0 pattern pyramid output in c++

Tags: c++

I am a Computer Science student learning c++. I am trying to get the output shown below but it seems something is going wrong as I am not getting the exact output. Please help me.I need following pyramid output:

```
   1
  0 1
 1 0 1
0 1 0 1
```

But I am getting the following output:

```
   1 0
  0 1 0 1
 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

What modifications should I make in my code to get the desired ouput?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int k;
    int n=4;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for(int l=0; l<n-i; l++)
        {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            k=0;
        }
        else
        {
            k=1;
        }
        for(int j=0; j<=(2*i-1); j++)
        {
            cout<<k<<" ";
            if(k==0)
            {
                k=1;
            }
            else
            {
                k=0;
            }
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Well, since you're lines are always twice as large as they should be, have you tried removing the factor `2` in your last `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

When `i` goes 1, 2, 3, 4, `j=0; j<=(2*i-1); ++j` tests`<=` 2*1-1, 2*2-1, 2*3-1, 2*4-1 which is 1, 3, 5, 7.  C;learly that's not the correct number of values to print on each of the four lines.  `j < i` looks about right...!